Client side refresh() gives CORS error in Chrome
Here is another of those CORS questions from a person who is not completely understanding the issue, because he works with frameworks only ;)
I'm using nuxt3 plus nuxt-graphql-client
My Apollo server runs on http://localhost:3001, Nuxt runs on http://localhost:3000
In the <script setup> section of a component, it is simple to async await a GraphQL call and use the result for rendering.
I believe this is a SSR type of call.
However, at runtime, when a user changes an input, I would like to refresh() the result set with the updated search text.
<script setup>
const searchQuery = ref('')
const { data, refresh } = await useAsyncGql('MyGqlQuery', { name: { contains: searchQuery.value })
const items = computed(() => data.value?.items || [])

// on keyboard input
const onKeyboardInput = async (newSearchQuery) => {
  searchQuery.value = newSearchQuery
  await refresh() // browser throws a CORS error  
}
</script>

In the onKeyboardInput() function the browser complains by throwing a CORS error. Probably already in preflight.
I have tried the useGqlHeaders({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3001' }) and useGqlCors({ mode: 'cors'}) functions (but maybe completely wrong).
Obviously, I am doing something stupid. But I'd really like to understand what settings are required, or how to get this to work. Any pointers to overcome my lack of understanding are highly appreciated.

Ok, being an idiot, but hopefully help others; add CORS to the Apollo server instance! This is not a client issue...

Well, strictly speaking, it's also a client issue: the client/the browser decides that it wants CORS support from the server. ;) The request itself would work completely fine without any CORS middleware when invoked by another kind of client, e.g. from Postman or another, non-browser process.
